# Enter event not working for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an event for the enter key in a modal dialog , but it is not working for some reason.

```
  (function () {
        'use strict';

        var app = angular.module('myModule')
        .directive('ngEnterKey', function() {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {

                element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
                    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;

                    // If enter key is pressed
                    if (keyCode === 13) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            // Evaluate the expression
                            scope.$eval(attrs.dlEnterKey);
                        });

                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            };
        });

 <div ngEnterKey="logout()">
...
<a href="#" data-ng-click="logout()">Yes </a>
<a href="#" data-ng-click="cancel()">No </a>
...
 </div>
```

I'm not sure why the event is not getting triggered. The logout method is working properly on the button click.

Comment: What is the attribute `dlEnterKey`? It should also be `<div ng-enter-key` - not `ngEnterKey`

Comment: sorry that is a typo. it is scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnterKey);

Comment: Poor practice to use `ng-` prefixes for custom directives. Better to reserve that for angular core so no potential future conflicts arise and also so later on someone doesn't assume it is part of the core API while doing maintenance

Answer (score 0):

Change your element to this:

```
<div ng-enter-key="logout()">
```

The attribute used to trigger the directive to be used has to follow a certain convention.

According to the [docs for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> - Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
> - Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Also, it is probably not considered good form to use the "ng-" prefix for any of your types, unless you intend to be contributing this type directly to the angular source.

Comment: Taking your suggestion, I changed it to daEnterKey in the Javascript and da-Enter-Key in the HTML. However it is still not working. Does it have to do anything with the fact that I am using this in a modal dialog?

Comment: "However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms". Make it lower case.